# About jackson convert Java dataType

Tags: java, jackson

There's a project use Jackson, and have a Java object Data. In the object, there's a property, and it's also a object Raw. In this object,there's a property `List<Object[]>`
e.g:

```
public class Data{
    Raw raw;
}

public class Raw{
    List<Object[]> list;
}
```

If the `Object[]` have a data type: `long`, and I give a value: 123, then the Jackson will convert this data type to `int`,

i.e: If the value's `length < long && > int` , the data type is also `long`, if `length < int`, the data type will become `int`.

I use the method:

```
 byte[] bytes = writeValueAsBytes(Data), Data data = readValue(bytes, Data.class)
```

How could I keep the original data type when it is converted?

Comment: You can't.  JSON has no conception of ints or longs.

Comment: @SLaks what have conception about Json? I feel that Json can handle String well, other type can't handle very well? how could I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson does what I think you want:

```
@Test
public void testJackson() throws Exception {
    List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
    numbers.add(100L);
    numbers.add(new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1000L);
    numbers.add(10.0);
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(numbers));
    List<Number> newNumbers = om.readValue(om.writeValueAsString(numbers), ArrayList.class);
    System.out.println(newNumbers);
    assertEquals(Integer.class, newNumbers.get(0).getClass());
    assertEquals(newNumbers.get(1).getClass(), Long.class);
    assertTrue(! numbers.equals(newNumbers) );
}
```

However `numbers` will not equal `newNumbers` because `100L` should be an integer.
The maximum number that JSON can handle is a 64 bit double precision.

If your doing data serialization like for binary images then I would encode the data in Base64.

Comment: yes,it's what you think, first, thank you, but I get data from database,and will convert the database type to java type by DB type's length,then it will transfer by network, and I will receive the data, then insert into the other DB'table which have the same type, you say that The maximum number that JSON can handle is a 64 bit double precision. why it can't keep 100L to long type? And what can I do to keep the type not become?

Comment: As @SLaks said because the type information is lost and JSON doesn't have a way to differentiate integers from longs. I recommend you just make your list `List<Long> list` which probably work or just normalize your List<Object> on the other end to be all longs.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use type of `Number` instead, so you can easily get values as whatever type you want. As others point out, JSON only has "integer number" type, and there is nothing in content to point out expected Java type. This means that your Class must indicate expected type; and if all you suggest is `Object`, it is free to choose the most efficient representation.